# Web Page Creation notepad++

Tags: notepad++, html

*Beginner*
Entered this code into a validator and was receiving a stray end error and bad character errors. They gave me solutions but I have no idea what these mean. Couldn't find anything online without bringing me to this site. This is html5 and I am using notepad++ if this helps any..

`<ul>
        <li>a< href="http://Blackboard.mccneb.edu">Blackboard Course Web Site</a> </li>
        <li>a< href="http://www.mccneb.edu">Metro Web Site</a> </li>
        <li>a< href="http://validator.w3.org">W3C (X)HTML Validator</a> </li>
        <li>a< href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/">W3C CSS Validator</a> </li>
    </ul>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem is syntax mistake. 
Instead of

```
<a href="http://Blackboard.mccneb.edu">Blackboard Course Web Site>
```

use

```
<a href="http://Blackboard.mccneb.edu">Blackboard Course Web Site</a>
```

The [W3Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/) should be able to help if you have similar questions or problems in the future.

Comment: Feel very embarrassed for missing that simple error. Thanks for the help!